# How to get tag location in javascript without changing the DOM

Tags: javascript, html

Lets say I have the following code:

```
<body>
  <a>1</a>
  <a>2</a>
</body>
<script>
var as = document.getElementByTagName('a');
for(var i=1; i<=as.length; i++) {
  as[i].onclick = function(){
    alert(i);
  }
}
</script>
```

When I click on any of the `a` tags it will alert 2!
I know why, but how do I get passed it?

Comment: It start at 0, replace `i=1` by `i=0`

Comment: There is no function getElementByTagName, but getElementsByTagName.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

need to add some closure to save the value of i, because the onlick function will be called after that the loop is finished and the value of i has changed

```
as[i].onclick = (function(i2){
    return function(){
        alert(i2);
    };
})(i);
```

Comment: Closure. That's what I needed to hear.

Answer (score 1):

This is a scoping issue. Your `for` loop will have finished before any clicks are registered, so `i` will always be `2`. You can avoid this by using a functional [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop which will retain your scope:

```
var as = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
[].forEach.call(as, function (el, i) {
  el.onclick = function(){
    alert(i);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://api.jquery.com/index/) will give you current position of tag in html, You can use following code :

```
$('a').on('click',function(){
console.log($(this).index());
});
```